# Missing pagination - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Basically I am using shortcode to query all the blog posts on a page.
It works nice, except one little detail - there is no pagination. There are 20 test posts, and as you can `posts_per_page` is set to `5` so it should generate links with next pages on the bottom. Using [Vantage Theme](http://siteorigin.com/theme/vantage/).

What am I missing here?

```
<?php

function getblogpostsmain($atts, $content = null) {


   $return_string .= '<div class="blog-main">';
   query_posts (array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),

   ));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $return_string .= '<h1 class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'  </a></h1><div class="infoblog">Posted on '.get_the_date().' in '.get_the_category_list(__( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) ).'</div> ';
    $return_string .= '<p class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '';
endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</div>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

?>
```

Comment: There's probably an issue with the theme. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are posting doesn't have the pagination. Assuming you are adding your code to the [Vantage free theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/vantage), you need to add this to your code.

```
vantage_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
```

That's the function the vantage theme uses for the pagination. You will need to try and see how it works and how you can implement it.

Comment: You should make a comment to improve my answer or accept my answer. Don't leave questions open.